# Intercambiar elementos de una lista en parejas

Tags: python

No me va este código dónde tengo que intercambiar elementos de una lista en parejas:

```
def exchange(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return l
    else:
        result = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(l) - 1:
            result += [l[i+1]] + [l[i]]
            i += 2
            if len(l) % 2 == 1:
                result += [l[len(l)-1]]
        return result
```

Comment: el código va como texto y no como imagen, edita esto y colocalo como texto por favor

Comment: No me deja me pone que es incorrecto por eso lo he puesto como imagen

Comment: que pone como incorrecto? @Javocho? pega el código, luego elígelo y dale clic al ícono `{}` y ay con eso debe aparecer formateado

Comment: Ahora ya me va. Gracias element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente lo que tiene que hacer tu código es intercambiar los elementos de índice par con los de índice impar, es decir `l[0]` se intercambia con `l[1]`, `l2[2]` con `l[3]`, etc. Cuando el número de elementos es impar, el último "sobra" en cierta forma, y no se intercambia con nadie.

Tu código ya casi lo hacía, excepto que no manejabas bien el caso "número impar de elementos", pues en ese caso el último elemento debe añadirse al final, y no *en cada iteración* como estabas haciendo.

Este es tu código modificado para que el último elemento se añada al final. Bastaba mover fuera del bucle unas líneas:

```
def exchange(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return l
    else:
        result = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(l) - 1:
            result += [l[i+1]] + [l[i]]
            i += 2
        if len(l) % 2 == 1:
            result += [l[len(l)-1]]
        return result
```

Ahora bien, tu código no modifica realmente el parámetro `l`. Es decir, si lo invocas con:  `exchange(datos)`, la variable `datos` no resulta modificada, sino que se construye una nueva lista que se retorna como resultado. Tendrás que hacer `datos = exchange(datos)` para ver los cambios reflejados en esa variable.

Otra alternativa sería que la lista pasada como parámetro fuera modificada *in situ*, en lugar de crear una nueva. El siguiente código (que es más corto) hace eso:

```
def exchange(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return l
    for i in range(0, 2*len(l)//2-1, 2):
        l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]
```

Uso aquí algunos trucos:

- La función `range(a,b,c)` da una serie de enteros que comienzan en `a`, terminan antes de alcanzar o rebasar `b` y están espaciados de `c` en `c` unidades. En mi caso lo uso para ir generando los índices `i` que comiencen en cero, avancen de 2 en 2, y terminen antes del último índice par válido.
- Para generar el último índice par válido uso el truco de hacer la división entera entre 2 (`//2`) y multiplicar por 2 el resultado. Así, si el número de elementos de la lista era par (por ejemplo 10), esa expresión daría como resultado 10. Pero si era impar (por ejemplo 9) dará 8. Eso me evita tener que mirar y tratar de forma especial si el número de elementos era par o impar. Si es impar, el bucle se detendrá antes de llegar al último que por tanto no se tocará.
- Para intercambiar dos valores utilizo el truco pitónico `a, b = b, a` que permite intercambiar dos variables sin necesidad de otra intermedia. En este caso los elementos a intercambiar son dos de la lista `l`.

Si invocas este por ejemplo así:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
exchange(l)
```

La variable `l` resultará modificada. La función no retorna nada, sino que modifica la lista recibida como parámetro. Tras la ejecución el nuevo valor de `l` es:

```
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Las listas tienen la función `sort` para ordenarlas.

```
lista = ["2","1","3"]
lista.sort()
print(lista)

>>>["1","2","3"]
```

Comment: pero es que el caso no es ordenarlas sino intercambiar los elementos en parejas